# Springboot project failing to run. SQL BeanCreationException error in logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, beancreationexception

Im trying to make a REST api using springboot. Normally I would use PHPMyAdmin for the database but trying H2 out for the first time.

Havnt seen these issues come up in my old projects because I make the SQL database outside the project using PHPMyAdmin.

Any help would be extremely grateful.

This is the Maven Output
Maven output

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #2 of URL [file:/C:/Users/Brendan%20Ahern/Desktop/takehomeproject/api_java_project/api_java_project/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE accounts ( accountnumber int(9) NOT NULL, pin int(4) NOT NULL, balance int(11) NOT NULL, overdraft int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS ( ACCOUNTNUMBER INT(9) NOT NULL, PIN INT(4) NOT NULL, BALANCE INT(11) NOT NULL, OVERDRAFT INT(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=[*]INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=LATIN1"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE accounts ( accountnumber int(9) NOT NULL, pin int(4) NOT NULL, balance int(11) NOT NULL, overdraft int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 [42001-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.example.api_java_project.ApiJavaProjectApplication.main(ApiJavaProjectApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
```

This is my schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;

CREATE TABLE accounts (
  accountnumber int(9) NOT NULL,
  pin int(4) NOT NULL,
  balance int(11) NOT NULL,
  overdraft int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS atm;

CREATE TABLE atm (
  note_value String NOT NULL,
  note_amount int(11) NOT NULL


) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is my Account object class

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    @Id
    private int accountNumber;
    private int pin;
    private double balance;
    private double overdraft;

    public Account() {

    }

    public Account(int accountNumber, int pin, double balance, double overdraft) {
        super();
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.pin = pin;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.overdraft = overdraft;
    }

    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(Integer accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }
    public int getPin() {
        return pin;
    }
    public void setPin(int pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public Double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void setBalance(Double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public Double getOverdraft() {
        return overdraft;
    }
    public void setOverdraft(Double overdraft) {
        this.overdraft = overdraft;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[*]` mark in exceptions from H2 indicates a position of parser error:

```sql
… ) ENGINE=[*]INNODB …
```

You have two problems here.

1. You cannot use `ENGINE=InnoDB` etc. in H2 unless MySQL or MariaDB compatibility mode was enabled, you need to append the related flags (`;MODE=MySQL` and possibly others) to JDBC URL:
   https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility
   You also need to upgrade H2 to a more recent version, because old unsupported H2 1.4.200 is more restrictive here and cannot parse `latin1` as charset name (or you can replace it with `UTF8`).
2. There is no such data types as `STRING` in H2 and in the real MySQL too, you need to use some valid data type, for example, `VARCHAR(100)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually tells you the cause of your error.

```
expected "identifier";
```

You must specify a `PRIMARY KEY` value for the tables you want to create.

Additionally, if you do not want to assign the `PRIMARY KEY` value manually, do not forget to add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` definition for automatic assignment.